# Compare two images with python exclude shadows

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Trying to figure out the process of comparing two images and find the differences, but I got into a problem, which is : shadows.

All I want is a clean selection of the shirt. See images below.

All I got is this piece of code.

```py
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
import cv2
import numpy as np

before = cv2.imread('source.jpg')
after = cv2.imread('target.jpg')

# Convert images to grayscale
before_gray = cv2.cvtColor(before, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
after_gray = cv2.cvtColor(after, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Compute SSIM between two images
(score, diff) = compare_ssim(before_gray, after_gray, full=True)
print("Image similarity", score)

# The diff image contains the actual image differences between the two images
# and is represented as a floating point data type in the range [0,1] 
# so we must convert the array to 8-bit unsigned integers in the range
# [0,255] before we can use it with OpenCV
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")

# Threshold the difference image, followed by finding contours to
# obtain the regions of the two input images that differ
thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

mask = np.zeros(before.shape, dtype='uint8')
filled_after = after.copy()

for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 40:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(before, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(after, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], 0, (0,255,0), -5)
        cv2.drawContours(filled_after, [c], 0, (0,255,0), -1)

cv2.imwrite('output.jpg',mask)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

source : 
[image]

target :
[image]

output : 
[image]

expected output : 
[image]

Comment: Why not just color thresholding (or even grayscale thresholding) to get the shirt? It feels quite "cumbersome" to "subtract" the mannequin here. Nevertheless, also with your approach the actual solution is using morphological opening to get rid of the thin contours coming from the shadows. Have a look at OpenCV's [`morphologyEx`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f).

Comment: @HansHirse hmm...interesting...but the colours of the clothing will always change...or I didn't really understand what you are trying to say...

Comment: Try using inRange() to threshold in HSV colorspace. White-black (gray shades) have zero saturation. So just get the blue HSV values and get the outer filled contour.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way. It uses the fact that gray shades (white/gray/black) have no saturation. So one can just threshold a range of values in Saturation channel after converting to HSV.

```
Read the input

Then I convert to HSV and extract just the Saturation channel.

I then use inRange() to threshold it.

But it has some slight black spots and some white streaks. So I use morphology open and close to fill those regions. 

Then save the result.
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image as HSV and select the saturation channel
img = cv2.imread("mizuno.jpg")
sat = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,1]

# select the lower and upper bounds for thresholding
lower =(60) # lower bound for each channel
upper = (180) # upper bound for each channel

# threshold to create the mask and then apply morphology to close small spots
mask = cv2.inRange(sat, lower, upper)
kernel = np.ones((7,7), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("mizuno_mask.png", mask)
```

[image]

Comment: nice try ! i test it on few images, and noticed that it's working on plain colours. https://ibb.co/c39dTss this is an example :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try to **segment** the `target` image using any **clustering** method like K-means. I wrote something about segmentation of images in [this tutorial](https://www.alessiovaccaro.com/resources/clustering-land-cover-classification.php#5.-Segmentazione-dell'immagine-tramite-clustering)
.

Once you obtain a mask (ones and zeros [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bjv2.jpg)) that indicates what is "shirt" (ones) and what "is not shirt" (zeros) you can multiply it to your `output` image to obtain the `expected output`.

To segment the image using clustering you can use the `cv2.kmeans()` function. Something about it [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html#color-quantization).

This method is **fully automatizable**.

Comment: would appreciate a piece of code to try it in my scenario. ! Grazie !

Answer (score 0):

From your images and comments I take that you have influence on the image acquisition.

The solution is quite simple and known in the movie and tv industrie for many years.

Paint the mannequin with a highly saturated matte colour and use chroma keying to remove it from your images.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key

Another maybe even simpler solution is to improve your lighting to avoid those shadows on the mannequin.

Comment: unfortunately Chroma key is not an option :( but thank you for your suggestion.